# "performSegueWithIdentifier" gives fatal error

Tags: ios, swift

I am new in `iOS`-`Swift`. I created simple app, first time after log in `"performSegueWithIdentifier"` works fine but After logout I'm coming back to root view controller if I again log in, `"performSegueWithIdentifier"` gives me `fetal error (crash)`. I am not setting any property from my login view. I don't understand y its working fine for the first time and gives error second time.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) { 
    super.viewDidAppear(animated) 
    self.login() 
}

func login() { 
    if user == nil { 
        self.presentViewController(logInView, animated: false, completion: nil)
    } else {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Home", sender: self) // Here I m getting error after logout when i log in again. 
    } 
}
```

in my second view, after logout i have written this:

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(false)
```

Error I get is the following:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

My storyboard hierarchy is:
Navigation controller - ViewController(loginview)- TabbarController(HomeView)- Four tabs Two view controllers and two TableViewControllers.
From one of the TableViewController I am calling method

self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(false)

Then its coming back to ViewController(loginview) but if i again try to login that time Tabbar view controller is not present. i m getting this by following code:

print("NextView = (storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Home"))") // Here only i m getting fetal error.

Comment: When you logout, what are you setting as the rootviewcontroller

Comment: You should change rootviewcontroller after login.

Comment: You need to show the code that is causing the crash and the error log. Without those there is literally nothing we can do.

Comment: @mitul Can you tell me how can i change the root view controller.
Thanks all for replying

Comment: Code should go in your question. Not in a comment. What is the error message being shown?

Comment: Did you try and debug, see if user is nil or has a value when it hits the `login()` method?

Comment: Put a break point and tell where you are getting this error? In which line?

Comment: is your view in navigation hierarchy ?

Comment: can you share more code means your root view controller and log screen code so that we can understand the flow where you are doing mistake

Answer (score 0):

You can change the root view controller like this:

```
 let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) // "Main" is storyboard name
 let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("id") as UITabBarController  
   UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController = viewController;
```